How to change Linux Mint sounds?
I would like to know how to change the sounds in Linux Mint, such as startup, notifications and shutdown.
How could I change these settings?

THis will sound unsurprising, but: in the Notifications/Sounds setting of your desktop environment, in the normal settings environment. We don't know which desktop environment you're using, but I bet you can find the settings in that and include a screenshot of that.
